# Access pixel value in a cvMat image in OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

I have used Canny edge detector to successfully identify the edges of a given image. I'm struggling with finding specific points on this detected edge line.

My approach:

I used the `cv::canny` function in opencv and the output is stored in `cv::Mat` format. I want to iterate through the all values of the matrix and identify all those pixels where the edge is present so that I can detect the specific points on the detected edge line.

Function used:

```
cv::Canny(frame_gray,contours,50,150);
```

The output is stored in `contours` and it is of type `CV_8UC3`

To access the pixel value, have tried

```
contours.at<int>(i,j) != 0
```

and also

```
contours.at<uchar>(i,j) != 0
```

Will greatly appreciate help in the above. If the approach is correct and am missing something or else if i should try another approach
Thanks

Edit:

```
for(int i=0;i<img_width;i++)
 { 
  if((int)contours.at<uchar>(i,neckcenter.y) > 0 ) 
  { 
    Point multipoints(i,neckcenter.y); 
    circle( contours, multipoints, neckpoint, Scalar( 255, 0, 0 ),4, 8, 0 );
    cout << (int)contours.at<uchar>(i,neckcenter.y) << endl; 
  }
 }
```

I am using the above code which forms a small circle of radius 1 (defined by neckpoint) where it detects a point on and edge. The neckcenter.y is a constant value derived from an earlier calculation. What am i doing wrong here ?

Output of the code -

[image: The diamond points should come on the edges whereas they are coming on black space]

Answer (score 2):

you probably want a grayscale pass before applying Canny:

```
Mat gray;
cvtColor(bgr,gray,CV_BGR2GRAY); // now gray is a 8bit, uchar Mat

Mat contours;
cv::Canny(gray,contours,50,150);

// now you're safe to use:
uchar value = contours.at<uchar>(i,j);
```

Comment: thanx for replying...i have used the gray scale pass (same as you've mentioned) but still the points are not detected on the edges. It seems that the function is not able to read the edge pixels. Will appreciate any suggestions.. thanks

Comment: total *different* problem now, no ?

Comment: can you tell me what will be the range of value of pixel where the edge is present ? because while using uchar, values are not in readbable format in the terminal and while using int the value ranges from 255 to 1494300928

Comment: cout << (int) m.at<uchar>(i,j);// oh, about the printing

Comment: high value on edge, low if not

Comment: i've edited my question to explain my approach further

Answer (score 1):

The syntax:

```
contours.at<uchar>(i,j)
```

Is correct for your case in terms of data type (i.e. a grayscale image). The problem is possibly hinted at by this line:

```
for(int i=0;i<img_width;i++)
```

When you access OpenCV pixels using `at`, you must specify the pixel position as `(row, col)`, so your indexing is the wrong way round. Try this in all places where you access pixels:

```
contours.at<uchar>(j,i)
```

From the [OpenCV documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/user_guide/ug_mat.html):

[image]

Comment: thnx fr replying..so you are suggesting that i should make `if((int)contours.at<uchar>(i,neckcenter.y) > 0 )` to `if((int)contours.at<uchar>(neckcenter.y,i) > 0 )` ? I tried this but now I am getting no points in output.

Comment: @ShivangDoshi well, you may have other problems, but getting your x and y coordinates reversed was certainly a major one. Using `img.at<uchar>(y,x) > 0` is the correct test - make sure you are using the correct addressing everywhere now.

Comment: @ShivangDoshi not without seeing your amended code - you *did* make sure you have `CV_8UC1` output? In your question you say `CV_8UC3` so maybe you're missing a greyscale conversion?

Answer (score 0):

You have a 3 channel image of the type unsigned char. To access it you should use the cv::Vec3b type. Here is how to do it:

```
int channel = 0;//or 1 or 2
contours.at<cv::Vec3b>(i,j)[channel]
```

To check if all elements are 0:

```
contours.at<cv::Vec3b>(i,j)[0]==0 && contours.at<cv::Vec3b>(i,j)[1]==0 && contours.at<cv::Vec3b>(i,j)[2]==0
```

But where do you have the information that the image type of contours is CV_8UC3 ?